# Find Duplicates using Derived Tables Only

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

cte can be a memory hog sometimes. The following SQL works great until there are memory issues with other databases.

Any ideas how to reproduce Row_Number Over Partition using derived tables.

Table A holds the Work phone.
Table B holds the Id.
We have to join Table A with Table B in order to find duplicates in Table B; using the phone as the duplicate criteria.

This SQL works. I just want to see suggestions using derived tables instead.

```
;WITH cte
                 AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a.WorkPhone ORDER BY b.id DESC ) AS
                            rownumber
                            ,
                            a.WorkPhone,
                            a.id
                     FROM   TableB B
                            JOIN TableA a
                              ON b.GroupofLeadsid = a.id
                     WHERE  b.GroupofLeads = @GroupofLeads
                            AND NOT a.WorkPhone IS NULL
                            AND a.WorkPhone <> '')

            UPDATE b
            SET    b.deleteflag = 1
            FROM   TableB b
                   JOIN cte t
                     ON b.id = t.id
            WHERE  b.GroupofLeads = @GroupofLeads
                   AND rownumber > 1
```

Comment: The whole concept of this question doesn't make sense. Derived tables have no different performance characteristics from CTEs, they just have a slightly less flexible syntax. Both are basically inline views.

Comment: Try running CTE vs Derived Tables while looking at query analyzer and you will see big differences in performance.

Comment: No there isn't. Any difference in performance you think you saw will be attributable to something else. e.g. parameter sniffing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update TableB
Set deleteflag = 1
From TableB As B
    Join    (
            Select Row_Number() Over ( Partition By A.WorkPhone Order By B.Id Desc ) As RowNum
                , A.WorkPhone, A.Id
                , B.Id
            From TableB As B1
                Join TableA As A1
                    On A1.id = B1.GroupOfLeadsId
            Where B1.GroupOfLeadsId = @GroupOfLeads
                And A.WorkPhone <> ''
            ) As CTE
        On CTE.Id = B.Id
Where CTE.RowNum > 1
```

Another choice:

```
Update TableB
Set deleteflag = 1
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From    (
                        Select Row_Number() Over ( Partition By A.WorkPhone Order By B.Id Desc ) As RowNum
                            , B.Id
                        From TableB As B1
                            Join TableA As A1
                                On A1.id = B1.GroupOfLeadsId
                        Where B1.GroupOfLeadsId = @GroupOfLeads
                            And A.WorkPhone <> ''
                        ) As CTE
                Where CTE.RowNum > 1
                    And CTE.Id = TableB.Id
                )
```